# How to use Perl to write the contents of a C struct to a file

Tags: perl

I have a C structure like this

```
struct _RxMsg {
    int index;
    int status;
    unsigned char packet[1024];
} rx_msg;
```

I can access this structure in Perl using the [`Convert::Binary::C`](https://metacpan.org/module/Convert%3a%3aBinary%3a%3aC) module. The element `packet[1024]` is populated with some binary data that has arrived over the network (assume the contents of a text file).

If I dump the element I can see the contents.

```
open $fp, '>>', "file.txt" or die $!;
binmode $fp;      /* I set binmode but still no good */  
for ($rx_msg->{packet}) {
  print $fp @$_;  /* This is writing the binary content as hex into the file. */
}
```

But the contents that are written to the file are in hex, when I want to write the simple binary contents of `rx_msg->{packet}`

Comment: If you write binary data, it's not a text file.

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry maybe my explanation was not quite right. The problem is i received some contents of a file from network, and stored it into the 'C' structure. I want to create a file and its binary content should be the values in the 'C' structure. Is my requirement bit better to understand now?

Comment: No, that doesn't clarify it at all. I understand what it means to write binary content to a file, but that makes it a binary file, not a text file. Anyway, I suspect that `pack()` is the function you're looking for.

Comment: What's the output of `{ use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($rx_msg->{packet})); }`?

Comment: @ikegami: looks to me from the Convert::Binary::C doc like that will be like `[1, 255, 42, ...]`

Comment: Yes!, thanks @Barmar, ikegami and ysth ., it is pack() function that i was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually printing the decimal representation the `char` values, not their hex representation. What you want to do is print each number as a byte. `chr` and `pack 'C'` can be used to convert numbers to bytes.

```
open(my $fh, '>>:raw', 'file.txt') or die $!;

# Same thing:
#open(my $fh, '>>', 'file.dat') or die $!;
#binmode($fh);

print($fh, pack('C*', @{ $rx_msg->{packet} }));
```